# Replace union all between three tables as join

Tags: oracle, join, union

I am new to oracle this could be simple.But I want to check if below union all can be replaced with some sort of join .

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3 from b,a
where a.col3=b.col3 and a.col4= b.col4
and b.col5= --filter conditions
union all
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3 from c,a
where C.col3=b.col3 and c.col4= b.col4
and c.col5= --filter conditions
and c.col6= -- extra conditions
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what a, b, and c represent? Or at least what the foreign keys are? This is possible, but you have to know the pk/fk relationships

Comment: @AnthonyE Constraints do not need to be known to query or to rewrite a query to others that are equivalent (in the sense that they return the same results for all inputs). (Table meanings are necessary & sufficient to query.) Under constraints certain other expressions return those same results in all cases that can arise. You can always blindly/mechanically rewrite a query to one that is equivalent. If the original is constraint-independent you'll rewrite one equivalent to that & otherwise the original relied on some constraints & you'll rewrite to one equivalent to that.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Posting code, give a [mcve]. (Outer joins are unions of inner join & some unmatched input rows extended by nulls. So they can be used to do unions by sufficiently massaging the input & output. Then also except/minus & antijoin.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your existing code using `join`.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, though, I would go for `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b
              where a.col3 = b.col3 and a.col4 = b.col4 and . . .
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from c
              where c.col3 = b.col3 and c.col4 = b.col4 and . . .
             );
```

Note:  Your original query will return duplicate rows in `a` if there are multiple matches in either `b` or `c`.  This version doesn't return such duplicates.  Usually, not returning duplicates is the desired behavior.

Comment: thanks for the reply gordon.. i have one more small tweak.. here instead of a.* if the choice of select is b.* and c.* how would that change the query as i  will have to display all6 columns but i want them only as 3
    select b.* from b join a where a.col =a.col
    union all
    select c.* from c join a where c.col=a.col

Comment: You should ask another question.  Naive use of `join` is likely to create duplicate rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it is helpful to you then

```
Select a.col1
     , a.col2
     , a.col3
from a
left
join b on a.col3=b.col3 and a.col4 = b.col4 and b.col5 = -- filter cindition
left
join c on c.col3 = b.col3 and c.col4 = b.col4 and c.col5 = filter condition and c.col6 = -- extra conditions
```